# A program asks to enter 10 values and sum them

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, foreach, eclipse-cdt

Using (For each) I want a program asks to enter 10 values from multiples of 10 and stores it inside an array and finds the sum of these numbers that were entered in this array ... the problem is that the code only handle the last element that I entered [The problem photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxRg0.png)

```
package lesson27task2Pac;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lesson27Task2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    

  
    int larr;
    Scanner scw = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Aarray Lenght :");
    larr=scw.nextInt();
    
    int [] array = new int [larr];
    
    
    Scanner sce = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter multiples :=====>");

    for (int e : array) {
    array[e] = sce.nextInt();
    }

    for (int e: array) {
        
        if (e % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println(e +"");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a multiple !!!");
        }
    
    }
    int sum = 0 ;
    for (int e : array) {
        sum = sum + e;
    }
    System.out.println("Summation of array elements : "+sum);}}
```

Answer (score 2):

This type of foreach loop

```
for (int e : array) {
   array[e] = sce.nextInt();
}
```

is returning the values of the array and putting it into the value `e`.

As the array has only the default values of `0`, you you always doing

```
array[0] = sce.nextInt();
```

Try using a normal for loop

```
for (int e = 0; e < array.length; e++)
{
    array[e] = sce.nextInt();
}
```